# To find the order of the group $G = \{x^i y^jz^k : x^3=y^3=z^3=e, xyz = z^2y^2x^2\}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, analysis

To find the order of the group 
$$G = \{x^i y^jz^k : x^3=y^3=z^3=e, xyz = z^2y^2x^2\}.$$

One can easily see that powers of $i,j,k$ varies in $0,1,2$.

Comment: I don't understand your notation.  Can you explain more exactly how $G$ is defined?

Comment: @Derek Are they not simply assuming that $G$ consists of (possibly empty) words from the alphabet $\{x, y, z\}$? I believe this is more than reasonable. Then the question is essentially giving a normal form and some defining relations.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. The group generated by $x,y,z$ subject to the four given relations is infinite. We could assume that every element of $G$ can be expressed as $x^iy^jz^k$, but then $G$ could have order $1,3$ or $9$ or $12$. And in the examples of order $12$, it is not true that $\langle x \rangle$, etc are normal in $G$.

Comment: @Derek That $\langle x\rangle$ etc. are not necessarily normal is an error in my answer. So then the "group" is not uniquely defined.